# How to get the file path I opened with a cmd file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe

Let's say I opened a file using a cmd/bat file that echoes the the path of a file, how do I get its path?

For example, I'm opening `c:/test.txt` using `x.cmd`:

**x.cmd**

```
@echo off

title hello

echo ******VARIABLE FOR THE PATH OF THE FILE?*******

pause
```

result: echoing **c:/test.txt** on the screen.

Comment: How are you calling `x.cmd`?

Comment: With "open with"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **[`Parameter Extensions`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)**

```
%~f1  Expand %1 to a Fully qualified path name - C:\utils\MyFile.txt
%~d1  Expand %1 to a Drive letter only - C:
%~p1  Expand %1 to a Path only e.g. \utils\ this includes a trailing 
      \ which will be interpreted as an escape character by some commands.  
%~n1  Expand %1 to a file Name without file extension or path - MyFile  
      or if only a path is present, with no trailing backslash, the last folder in that path.  
%~x1  Expand %1 to a file eXtension only - .txt  
%~s1  Change the meaning of f, n, s and x to reference the Short 8.3 name (if it exists.)  
%~1   Expand %1 removing any surrounding quotes (")  
%~a1  Display the file attributes of %1  
%~t1  Display the date/time of %1
```

---

```
@echo off

title <nul & title hello

echo\Path to argument %~1
echo\Path to argument %~1 %~f1
echo\Path to argument %~1 %~dpnx1

echo\Path to argument %~2
echo\Path to argument %~2 %~f2
echo\Path to argument %~2 %~dpnx2

echo\Path to argument %~3
echo\Path to argument %~3 %~f3
echo\Path to argument %~3 %~dpnx3

pause
```